# Create default childs to node in umbraco

Tags: c#, data-binding, umbraco, nodes, umbraco7

I'm trying to find out how to force node to create only one node child of other type ?

I have 'hotel' node and i want to add one 'rooms' node and one 'facilities' node ('rooms' create 'room' and 'facilities' create 'facility')

[by default when i will create hotel the system will create this 2 folders or to force him that he can create only one each](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1GZA.jpg)

I prefer to do it with the management system (if possible) but code behind be good also !

Thanks in advance for all helpers!

Comment: By "management system" do you mean in the Umbraco backoffice? e.g. restrict more than one 'Rooms' being added as a child to each 'Hotel' document?

Comment: image Added just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am concerned, I do not know a way to achieve this by means of the Umbraco backoffice.

However, you can use the [ContentService Events](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/events/contentservice-events) in order to cancel the creation of that particular page if it has been already created. The `ContentServiceSaving` method will fire up each time that you try to create a node in the CMS.

```
public class ContentServiceEventsController : ApplicationEventHandler
{
    protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
      ContentService.Saving += ContentServiceSaving;
    }

    private void ContentServiceSaving(IContentService sender, SaveEventArgs<IContent> e)
    {

      switch (e.Entity.ContentType.Alias)
      {
        case "RoomsDocumentTypeAlias":
        case "FacilitiesDocumentTypeAlias":

        // Do your logic to detect if your Hotel node "Hilton eilat queen of sheba" 
        // already contains either a Rooms node or a Facilities node underneath.
        // If so, cancel the creation of the event of a new one.
        e.Cancel = true;
        break;

        default:
               break;
      }
    }
```